# Как правильно отфильтровать DataTable?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

**КОД(условный)**

```
string str_pole_1;

     str_pole_1 = "pole_1_zp_2";

    DataTable dt_tbl_1_msql = new DataTable();               

    MySqlDtAdp_0.Fill(dt_tbl_1_msql); // -> DataTable

    dt_tbl_1_msql.DefaultView.RowFilter = "pole_1 = '" + str_pole_1 + "'"; // фильтр         

     dataGridView1.DataSource = dt_tbl_1_msql; 
     Application.DoEvents();

for (int s2_t = s1_t-1; s2_t <= f1_f; s2_t++ )// 
{
    // 
    // ... код ...
    //      
    foreach (DataRow row_pl in dt_tbl_1_msql.Rows) // 
    {
        string vr_pole_2 = row_pl["pole_2"].ToString(); // поле  1
        string vr_pole_3 = row_pl["pole_3"].ToString(); // поле  2          
    }
}
```

**Сценарий**
1. Создаю DataTable.
2. Фильтрую DataTable по полю "pole_1" по значению "pole_1_zp_2".
3. Использую значения из DataTable в переменных vr_pole_2, vr_pole_3.

**Цель**
Добиться, чтобы в цикле foreach (DataRow row_pl in dt_tbl_1_msql.Rows) перебирались значения
pole_2_zp_4 pole_3_zp_4
pole_2_zp_5 pole_3_zp_5
pole_2_zp_6 pole_3_zp_6
соответственно для каждой переменной.
Т.е. чтобы записи соответствующие значению объявленному в переменной "str_pole_1 = "pole_1_zp_2";

**По факту**
В цикле foreach (DataRow row_pl in dt_tbl_1_msql.Rows) перебираются значения
pole_2_zp_1 pole_3_zp_1
pole_2_zp_2 pole_3_zp_2
pole_2_zp_3 pole_3_zp_3

**ВОПРОС**
1. Как сделать чтобы в цикле foreach (DataRow row_pl in dt_tbl_1_msql.Rows) перебирались значения
pole_2_zp_4 pole_3_zp_4
pole_2_zp_5 pole_3_zp_5
pole_2_zp_6 pole_3_zp_6
?
2. Если есть другие варианты решения, прошу поделиться.

**СКРИН** (условный)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, тег `WinForms` или `WPF`

Answer (score 1):

В самом `DataTable` после фильтрации строки остаются прежними. Они меняются в `DataView`. Вот с этим вью и нужно работать.

Вместо

```
foreach (DataRow row_pl in dt_tbl_1_msql.Rows)
```

пишем

```
foreach (DataRowView row_pl in dt_tbl_1_msql.DefaultView)
    // row_pl.Row - доступ к исходной строке
```